# XSS Payload not working

Tags: javascript, xss

I am learning Website Pen-testing and trying to find XSS vulnerability.I use Firefox Browser.

Here is the site's code for search bar:

[image: Site's code for search bar]

My payload is :
`a" onmouseover="ALeRT(X)" size="50`

which makes the code:
[image: New code].

However the Payload doesn't get executed as it should. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Do you see an error message in the console? Is the function `ALeRT` and the variable `X`  defined anywhere? What is the expected behaviour, and what happens instead?

Comment: @t.niese 1. No there is no related error in the console.                     2.'alert()' is the inbuilt function of JS.I changed the case just if 'alert()' was blacklisted and X is not variable here.                                                              3.I expected a message box with the message X but nothing as such happens.                                                                                                    An observation: 'onmouseover()' and size are not been apprehended as an attribute to input(See all attributes are in pink color but these are not).

Comment: Yes `alert()` is a buildin function, but `ALeRT`  is not, JS is case sensitive. Mot likely the value of `value`  is `a" onmouseover="ALeRT(X)" size="50` and not just `a`, so your code injection attempt failed.

Comment: @t.niese I also think it is taking the whole payload as value. Any idea to make payload successful?

Comment: @tonystark97 Maybe it is not vulnerable again script injection at that place? How should it be possible to determin form a picture? Anyhow, the question seems to be off topic.

Comment: I changed my payload to :    a" onmouseover="alert(1)" size="50         In Google Chrome I get the following error :     '?s=++a"+onmouseover%3Dalert(1)"+size%3D"50:473 A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js, is invoked via document.write.

Answer (score 0):

Since X is not defined, and it is not a variable, the alert function will not do anything and may error. Use alert(1) instead.